Tabla con pestañas anidadas
estoy desarollando una tabla con pestañas (tab) anidadas, las cuales a su vez anidan más subpestañas (subtab), mi problema es el siguiente, no puedo lograr que
solo una de esas subpestañas muestre su contenido al estar activa
que las demás subpestañas desaparezcan al togglear a una pestaña distinta
he intentado desanidando los botones del primer <td> y poniéndolos en :active pero no funcionó, agradezco cualquier ayuda que sea bienvenida


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const tabButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.tab-button');
  const subtabButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.subtab-button');
  const tabItems = document.querySelectorAll('.tab-item');
  const subtabItems = document.querySelectorAll('.subtab-item');

  tabButtons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
      const tabId = this.getAttribute('data-tab');

      // Remove active classes from all tabs and buttons
      tabButtons.forEach(btn => btn.classList.remove('active'));
      tabItems.forEach(item => item.classList.remove('active'));

      // Add active class to the clicked tab button and corresponding tab item
      this.classList.add('active');
      document.getElementById(tabId).classList.add('active');
    });
  });

  subtabButtons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
      const tabId = this.getAttribute('data-tab');

      // Remove active classes from all subtabs and buttons
      subtabButtons.forEach(btn => btn.classList.remove('active'));
      subtabItems.forEach(item => item.classList.remove('active'));

      // Add active class to the clicked subtab button and corresponding subtab item
      this.classList.add('active');
      document.getElementById(tabId).classList.add('active');
    });
  });
});
.tab-container {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.tab-table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.tab-button, .subtab-button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease, border-bottom-color 0.3s ease;
}

.tab-button.active, .subtab-button.active {
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-bottom-color: #333;
}

.tab-content {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.subtab-table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.subtab-item {
  display: none;
}

.subtab-item.active {
  display: block;
}

.subtab-button {
  display: block;
}

.subtab-button.active {
  display: none;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Tabla con pestañas anidadas</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="tab-container">
    <table class="tab-table">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button class="tab-button active" data-tab="tab1">Tab 1</button>
          <button class="tab-button" data-tab="tab2">Tab 2</button>
          <button class="tab-button" data-tab="tab3">Tab 3</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="tab1" class="tab-item active">
              <table class="subtab-table">
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <button class="subtab-button active" data-tab="tab1-1">Subtab 1-1</button>
                    <button class="subtab-button" data-tab="tab1-2">Subtab 1-2</button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <div class="tab-content">
                      <div id="tab1-1" class="subtab-item active">
                        <p>Content of Tab 1-1</p>
                      </div>
                      <div id="tab1-2" class="subtab-item">
                        <p>Content of Tab 1-2</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
            <div id="tab2" class="tab-item">
              <table class="subtab-table">
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <button class="subtab-button active" data-tab="tab2-1">Subtab 2-1</button>
                    <button class="subtab-button" data-tab="tab2-2">Subtab 2-2</button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <div class="tab-content">
                      <div id="tab2-1" class="subtab-item active">
                        <p>Content of Tab 2-1</p>
                      </div>
                      <div id="tab2-2" class="subtab-item">
                        <p>Content of Tab 2-2</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
            <div id="tab3" class="tab-item">
              <table class="subtab-table">
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <button class="subtab-button active" data-tab="tab3-1">Subtab 3-1</button>
                    <button class="subtab-button" data-tab="tab3-2">Subtab 3-2</button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <div class="tab-content">
                      <div id="tab3-1" class="subtab-item active">
                        <p>Content of Tab 3-1</p>
                      </div>
                      <div id="tab3-2" class="subtab-item">
                        <p>Content of Tab 3-2</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>



el resultado que busco lograr es este 

Y, al final, publicas una buena cantidad de código, dijiste cual es el requerimiento en el que trabajas, pero olvidaste decir cuál es tu problema.

@jachguate mi problema es que no logro que solo una de esas subpestañas muestre su contenido al estar activa

Esto parece más un requerimiento funcional para un programador contratado que una duda en StackOverflow. Si tienes un problema específico, creo que es mejor preparar un [mcve] para ese problema y resolverlo. Quizás es lo que estás intentando, pero por la especificación y la cantidad de código que publicas es difícil decirlo.  Puedes dejar así la pregunta y ver si alguien en la comunidad la toma y la responde. Yo la veo demasiado amplia y difusa, de acuerdo a [ask].

En tú código no veo algo como:
.tab-item {
  display: none;
}
.tab-item.active{
  display:unset;
}

Que sería el principal problema, también que estas repitiendo toda la lógica para los tab y sub-tab y ¿si tuvieras más tab anidados? (sería un lio)
Cada vez que presionas un botón, solo es necesario actualizar los botones hermanos y los tab que les corresponden a esos botones. Para eso basta con retroces al padre parentElement y usar un selector de hijos directos ':scope > .tab-button'


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
 const tabButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.tab-button');

  tabButtons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
      const tab = document.getElementById(this.dataset.tab);

      const buttons = this.parentElement.querySelectorAll(':scope > .tab-button');
      const tabItems = tab.parentElement.querySelectorAll(':scope > .tab-item');

      // Remove active classes from all tabs and buttons
      buttons.forEach(btn => btn.classList.remove('active'));
      tabItems.forEach(item => item.classList.remove('active'));

      // Add active class to the clicked tab button and corresponding tab item
      this.classList.add('active');
      tab.classList.add('active');
    });
  });


});
.tab-container {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.tab-table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.tab-button, .subtab-button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease, border-bottom-color 0.3s ease;
}

.tab-button.active, .subtab-button.active {
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-bottom-color: #333;
}

.tab-content {
  margin-top: 10px;
}


.tab-item {
  display: none;
}
.tab-item.active{
  display:unset;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Tabla con pestañas anidadas</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="tab-container">
    <table class="tab-table">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button class="tab-button active" data-tab="tab1">Tab 1</button>
          <button class="tab-button" data-tab="tab2">Tab 2</button>
          <button class="tab-button" data-tab="tab3">Tab 3</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="tab1" class="tab-item active">
              <table class="subtab-table">
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <button class="tab-button active" data-tab="tab1-1">Subtab 1-1</button>
                    <button class="tab-button" data-tab="tab1-2">Subtab 1-2</button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <div class="tab-content">
                      <div id="tab1-1" class="tab-item active">
                        <p>Content of Tab 1-1</p>
                      </div>
                      <div id="tab1-2" class="tab-item">
                        <p>Content of Tab 1-2</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
            <div id="tab2" class="tab-item">
              <table class="subtab-table">
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <button class="tab-button active" data-tab="tab2-1">Subtab 2-1</button>
                    <button class="tab-button" data-tab="tab2-2">Subtab 2-2</button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <div class="tab-content">
                      <div id="tab2-1" class="tab-item active">
                        <p>Content of Tab 2-1</p>
                      </div>
                      <div id="tab2-2" class="tab-item">
                        <p>Content of Tab 2-2</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
            <div id="tab3" class="tab-item">
              <table class="subtab-table">
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <button class="tab-button active" data-tab="tab3-1">Subtab 3-1</button>
                    <button class="tab-button" data-tab="tab3-2">Subtab 3-2</button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <div class="tab-content">
                      <div id="tab3-1" class="tab-item active">
                        <p>Content of Tab 3-1</p>
                      </div>
                      <div id="tab3-2" class="tab-item">
                        <p>Content of Tab 3-2</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>



